# Program to capture other's program stderr and stdout

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, stdout, io-redirection

I'd like to run a program as root that can intercept other's program `stderr` and `stdout`.
For example, say I start a `nodejs` server and somehow there's an error (with logs printed to `stderr`), if my program is running, I would like it to intercept this error.

Is that possible ? How should I do ?

Also, an idea that came to my mind was to replace `nodejs` binary by another one that starts `nodejs` and redirect `stderr` to a custom file. but I think it's too messy and I hope there's better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can control how `nodejs` is called you can redirect `stderr` to a named pipe and then read the named pipe from another command like this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/nodejs.stderr
nodejs 2>/tmp/nodejs.stderr
```

Then in some other shell type:

```
grep "Error Pattern" </tmp/nodejs.stderr
```

If you can't control how nodejs is called, then you can create a shell script to wrap those commands and call the shell script wherever nodejs is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not really what I'm looking for. I don't want the program to be run with the executable. The behavior I'm seeking is the following : Each time I run nodejs, like `node index.js` I want to get the log in the program (that is already running as a daemon).

Comment: Oh!  Sorry, I thought it was nodejs you were trying to capture the `stdout` of.  If you know the process ID of the server, you can type (as root) `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` this will show you what the server's file descriptors are hooked up to, and depending on that I might be able to suggest a way to attach to whatever it ends up being (it's often a pipe anyway.)

Comment: Alright, and how to you get the `stderr` from `/proc/<pid>/fd` and does it work on a running process ?

Comment: Each file descriptor that is open in a process is represented in `/proc/<pid>/fd` so `stderr` will be `/proc/<pid>/2`  This should be a symbolic link to something real, either a pseudo-tty if the process is running in a shell (which a server probably isn't) or a file that `stderr` is being logged to, or a pipe or even a socket.  Unless the process explicitly called `close(2)` to close `stderr` the entry will point to something, and some of those we can look at.  For instance if `/proc/<pid>/2` is a link to a  physical file we can use `tail -f <file>` to see  the server's `stderr`